# Too many materials

Tags: materials

I can't explain what the hell I did, but i have thousands of materials attached to my mesh, and my file is insanely big.

[image]

Is it possible to remove all of them and just keep one material for the entire mesh? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

You can select these materials in the outliner, and right click --> Delete.

They will be removed from your current blend file immediately.  You don't even need to restart blender or Purge the orphan data.  (If you opted for Unlink option instead of Delete, these materials will remain inside your blend file, and will be automatically removed if they are not linked with anything next time you load this file.)

Then, go to your object's material slot, see the button you used to add slot, the '+' button, there is a black triangle below it.  Click it and there is an option 'Clean Slots'.  Use that.